# How to make custom WPF ContentControl that supports drag-and-drop at design time?

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I want to create custom WPF control that has a single "child" control inside. Subclassing `ContentControl` or `UserControl` works, but has one flaw: these controls don't work in designer mode.

By "don't work" I mean this scenario: suppose I have a `Canvas` with my custom control in it. I want to put, say, a `Button` inside my control. I drag it from the toolbox, and it *appears* inside my control. However, XAML view shows that the new button actually belongs to `Canvas`, not to my control.

I can place it inside my control by manually editing XAML, but I want the designer to work too.

Interestingly, when I subclass `Canvas`, `Grid` or `Panel`, designer works as expected. However, these controls have *many* children, which is not what I need.

How can I make a single-child control that works in designer?

Comment: Here's a good link, looks like you're going to need s set of calsses with design time functionality  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/XPlorerBar2.aspx

Comment: Sorry, dude, I didn't mean to vote down, how do I revert the it?

Comment: @Dmitry I haven't found an answer by your link, but it is still very helpful for other WPF stuff I have to do, thanks.

Comment: @Dmitry: I made an "edit", see if you can revert your downvote now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about inheriting from `Border`? that way you could spare yourself the hassle with Designer Extensibility

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a content control I am writing and found an easy solution on this
[StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411910/problem-with-visualtreehelper-hittest-in-wpf/7162443#7162443).

Just implement the `HitTestCore` method:

```
protected override System.Windows.Media.HitTestResult HitTestCore(System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
{
    return new PointHitTestResult(this, hitTestParameters.HitPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44100159/wpf-how-to-enable-dragging-controls-into-contentcontrol-at-design-time).

But after digging and digging it seams that **the real answer is "NO"**, there isn't any official way to support dragging controls straight into a custom Content-Control at Design-Time, **even  implementing 'HitTestCore' as [Stephan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9867623/8021630) answer suggests, does not enable drag&drop at design-time for ContentControl**.

For such purposes you should consider inheriting from either Grid or Panel (to allow multiple child controls), or Border (to allow single child).