# WPF Get element at specific coordinates

Tags: c#, wpf, coordinate-systems

I have  Labels inside a Canvas, I need to get the label that intersects with coordinates X,Y?

Thanks!!

Comment: Coordinates relative to the canvas?  The window?  The screen?  Relative to the top-left corner?  Bottom-left?  Other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canvas.GetLeft(element), Canvas.GetTop(element) will get you any element's position.  Use ActualWidth and ActualHeight to form its complete rectangle.  You can iterate through the Children of the Canvas with a foreach.

**Edit:** CodeNaked pointed out that elements might be set with SetRight or SetBottom so I modified the sample code:

```
foreach (FrameworkElement nextElement in myCanvas.Children)
{
    double left = Canvas.GetLeft(nextElement);
    double top = Canvas.GetTop(nextElement);
    double right = Canvas.GetRight(nextElement);
    double bottom = Canvas.GetBottom(nextElement);
    if (double.IsNaN(left))
    {
        if (double.IsNaN(right) == false)
            left = right - nextElement.ActualWidth;
        else
            continue;
    }
    if (double.IsNaN(top))
    {
        if (double.IsNaN(bottom) == false)
            top = bottom - nextElement.ActualHeight;
        else
            continue;
    }
    Rect eleRect = new Rect(left, top, nextElement.ActualWidth, nextElement.ActualHeight);
    if (myXY.X >= eleRect.X && myXY.Y >= eleRect.Y && myXY.X <= eleRect.Right && myXY.Y <= eleRect.Bottom)
    {
        // Add to intersects list
    }
}
```

Comment: You're assuming the OP is not using the [Right](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.right.aspx) or [Bottom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.bottom.aspx) attached properties.

Comment: @CodeNaked: The comments in the question state they are looking based on Top Left.

Comment: @Scott - The comment says the X/Y coordinate are relative to the top-left, not that he's using the Top and Left attached properties. Either way I up voted this answer, since it's on the mark.

Comment: @AresAvatar - Uh, no it doesn't. Each attached property is used differently in the Canvas.ArrangeOverride. Setting the Right attached property doesn't affect the Left property.

Comment: Thanks!
I wonder why there is no function for that in WPF like hitTest!

Answer (score 6):

Simply use [`InputHitTest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputhittest.aspx) on your canvas, passing the coordinate you want as parameter. Note that `InputHitTest` is available on every `UIElement` and is not specific to canvas.

Comment: I don't think this gets all elements if the X,Y point overlaps more than one child.

Comment: You're right, this doesn't (the question implies it's not needed though "get the label"). However it will take into account margins and z-order, layout rounding, ...

Comment: True.  +1 for the simplicity of it.

Comment: Argh, I've spent so much time trying to churn out a nice working example.  Some caveats though, the hit test will return leaves of the visual tree.  So it won't return the Label, but the TextBlock (or other) that is presenting the content.  Using the [`VisualTreeHelper.HitTest()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608753.aspx) method is supposed to help with this but has another problem, it will actually skip the labels in the hit test.  The solution I've found (which took up most of my time) is to [search the visual tree ourselves](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411910).

Comment: You can use the HitTesting in WPF To traverse through multiple items, even if they overlap. You use VisualTreeHelper.HitTest with a callback.

For an example, take a look at this SO answer's hit test code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410146/dockable-windows-floating-window-and-mainwindow-menu-integration/6770950#6770950

Comment: @Nathan: Though subject to the problem that I mentioned in my previous comment.