# WPF hit testing UserControl and geometry

Tags: wpf, vb.net, hittest

I'm trying to make hit testing work between one user control and another user control.
I was looking at other questions and found that I have to put this in my user control.

```
Protected Overrides Function HitTestCore(hitTestParameters As System.Windows.Media.PointHitTestParameters) As System.Windows.Media.HitTestResult
Return New PointHitTestResult(Me, hitTestParameters.HitPoint)
End Function
```

I also have a filter which correctly shows the controls I want to hit-test somehow the `htcallback` isn't working.

Because I can't hit-test with my user control, I made a rectangle on the same spot and use that in my hit test. This doesn't seem to be working.

```
Dim hitTestGeometry = New RectangleGeometry()
hitTestGeometry.Rect = New Rect(_selected.breedte, _selected.hoogte, Canvas.GetLeft(_selected), Canvas.GetTop(_selected))
Dim pt As New Point
VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(WorkFlowCanvas, New HitTestFilterCallback(AddressOf wcFilter), New HitTestResultCallback(AddressOf verplaatsing), New GeometryHitTestParameters(hitTestGeometry))
```

I based my answer on this third reply.
[Problem with VisualTreeHelper.HitTest in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411910/problem-with-visualtreehelper-hittest-in-wpf/7162443#7162443)

What does he mean with this

> *if you want to hit-test against geometry you need to override that second overload as well*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides [HitTestCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598915.aspx) with a `PointHitTestParameters` argument there is a second method [HitTestCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598914.aspx) with a `GeometryHitTestParameters` argument.

This second one is called when you are hit-testing against a geometry.

Comment: Thanks I had changed my hittestmethod but didn't look at the parameters of the overridden method.